# How to parse this HTML Data into a tableview in swift

Tags: html, ios, json, swift, parsing

I am really struggling to parse the following HTML code. I want to be able to extract the following tags from a website

```
<div class = "subject">RED SOCK DAY 8th July</div>
<div class = "teacher">ELS</div>
<div class = "level">GENERAL</div>
<div class = "subject">This year,....</div>

<div class = "subject">STS Student...</div>
<div class = "teacher">RTN</div>
<div class = "level">GENERAL</div>
<div class = "subject">If you are....</div>
```

into an array of some sort (NSDictionaries?) and display into a tableview in swift. I know how to create a tableview and display static data of an array etc but struggle to get live data from a URL. Thoughts please on how to or an ideal link to help me please.

Comment: Why Are You not using JSON objects?

Comment: I struggle to understand how to use it... cause all of the tutorials seem to use data stored on the actual app and so I get lost on how to retrieve it when exchanging it with a live URL address.

Comment: Read about openWeatherMap api and see some github projects, there are many simple implementation for this web api. It uses rest api and JSON.

Comment: Thank you will look into it =)